# Вызов эксортируемой функции в Java приложении

Tags: функции, java, dll

Необходимо обратиться к функции экпортируемой из динамической библиотеки в JAVA приложении. На кроссплатформенность плевать. И не говорите почему именно JAVA а не C++ или C#, есть некоторые мотивы использовать именно этот язык.

```
package javawinapi;

    import java.io.*;

    public class JavaWinAPI {

        native static int sum(int x, int y);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            System.loadLibrary("sumka");        // загружаем библиотеку sumka.dll
            System.out.println(sum(2, 3));
        }
    }
```

в библиотеке всего одна функция. Компилятор возвращает:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javawinapi.JavaWinAPI.sum(II)I
    at javawinapi.JavaWinAPI.sum(Native Method)
    at javawinapi.JavaWinAPI.main(JavaWinAPI.java:24)
Java Result: 1
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну значит нет в библиотеке такой функции. Может, написано на С++ но объявлено без extern "C" .

Comment: Написано на Delphi 7 ^_^

Comment: В delphi тоже есть правила как описывать библиотечные функции - надо использовать stdcall и extern: http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/delphi/dll/index.htm